# Dynamic Allocation of an Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

For home-work, I need to define a function that allocate memory to an array of strings (which is into a struct).

The length of each string is given: MAX_WORD_LEN+1 (=10+1)
I have to allocate memory for `len` number of strings, `len` is recieved in the input.

Struct with the array of strings definition (given):

```
struct dict{
    int len;
    char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    char (*dict1)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
};
```

I don't understand the declaration `char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];`

- The function declaration is also given:
   **void createDict(struct dict* myDict);**

This is what  I wrote, but I'm not sure it works, and I have a difficult time checking it in the compiler. I also wrote it based on post from this and other websites and do not really understand it:

OPTION 1:

```
void createDict(struct dict* myDict)
{

    myDict->(*dict0) =  malloc( (myDict->len)*sizeof(char*));
    myDict->(*dict1) = (char**) malloc( (myDict->len)*sizeof(char*));

    for(int i=0;i<(myDict->len);i++)
    {
        (myDict->(*dict0)[i]) = (char*)malloc((MAX_WORD_LEN+1)*sizeof(char));
        (myDict->(*dict0)[i]) = (char*)malloc((MAX_WORD_LEN+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

OPTION 2:

```
(myDict->(*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]) = malloc((myDict->len) * sizeof(char*));
(myDict->(*dict1)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]) = malloc((myDict->len) * sizeof(char*));
```

Please explain to me...

Comment: Neither are correct for that declaration. The compiler alone should tell you that.

Comment: char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]; means an array of character pointers. But it seems you are trying to store a an array of characters (AKA string)

Comment: @Ifthikhan That is not an array of MAX_WORD_LEN+1 character pointers. It is a typed-pointer to an array of MAX_WORD_LEN+1 chars. Without the parens surrounding `*dict`, you would be correct. As presented, you are not.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to understand the difference between the following three declarations. For the sake of brevity, assume `N` is MAX_WORD_LEN+1 to match your sizing:

```
char data[N];      // array of N chars
char *data[N];     // array of N char *pointers* (i.e. char *)
char (*data)[N];   // pointer to array of N chars
```

Remember above all else, pointers are *variables* that hold an "address" and are implementation-defined. Just like an `int` variable holds the value of an implementation integer, a pointer variable holds an implementation address.

In almost all cases, you can properly `malloc()` memory for a pointer type using the sizeof() operator with the underlying target dereferenced. There are some cases where this is not intuitive or easily presentable, but the following should help:

```
// allocates sizeof(Type) block
Type *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));

// allocates N*sizeof(Type) contiguous blocks
//  note: we'll use this style later to answer your question
Type *pa = malloc(N * sizeof(*pa));
```

This will work no matter what `Type` is. This is important, because in your case you have a pointer declared as :

```
char (*dict)[N];
```

As we already discussed above, this declares a pointer of type (pointer-to-N-chars). Note that *no actual memory has been allocated yet. This is just a pointer; nothing more*. Therefore, you can safely allocate a single element using the above syntax as:

```
// allocate single block
char (*dict)[N] = malloc(sizeof(*dict));
```

But this only accounts for a single entry. You need `len` entries, so :

```
// allocate 'len' contiguous blocks each N chars in size
char (*dict)[N] = malloc(len * sizeof(*dict));
```

Now `dict` is safely addressable as an array from 0..(len-1). You can copy in your data such as:

```
strcpy(data[0], "test");
strcpy(data[1], "another test");
```

So long as the source string does not exceed N-chars (including the zero-terminator), this will work correctly.

Finally, don't forget to free your allocation when finished:

```
free(dict);
```

---

**Spoiler**

```
myDict->dict0 =  malloc( myDict->len * sizeof(*(myDict->dict0)));
myDict->dict1 =  malloc( myDict->len * sizeof(*(myDict->dict1)));
```

Comment: @user2191288 I sure hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration of the structure,

```
char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
```

means that `dict0` is a `pointer` to a character array of **MAX_WORD_LEN + 1** elements i.e. `char [11]`.

To initialize the field of your object, you can consider an *example* as shown below

```
void createDict(struct dict* myDict)
{
    myDict->dict0 = &glbarr;
    myDict->dict1 = &glbarr;
}
```

where `glbarr` is a global array defined as

```
char glbarr[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
```

Comment: [MAX_WORD_LEN+1] - is meant to be the lenght of every string in the array, I have to allocate memory for the arrays acording to the int "len" that i get from the input.  For example, if len is 5 i need to allocate memory for 5 strings of 11 lenght... I am not sure that waht you wrote do it.

Answer (score 0):

`char (*dict)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]` is a pointer to an array of `char[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]`. Or you can interpret it as an array of such arrays (a two-dimensional array).

Let's say
`typedef char MyString[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];`.

Then your declaration will look as `MyString *dict0;`
In other words, the `dict0` can be a pointer to the first element of an array of `MyString`. And this is what you should do.

I will not post the detailed solution (your teacher would not be happy with that).

I suggest also that you feel the difference between `char (*dict)[10];` and `char *dict[10];`.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference, also is not really my homework.. I start my studies next year, I am doing a little practicing till then.

Comment: so i need to allocate memory for the pointer *dict0 ?                         so is this write ? (myDict->(*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]) = malloc((myDict->len) * sizeof(char*));                                             \n what i wrote in OPTION 2

Comment: char *dict[10] is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.
You should malloc len*(MAX_WORD_LEN+1)*sizeof(char) bytes.
This will look as myDict->dict0 = malloc(...)

Comment: I asked about char(*dict)[11], I think it is a pointer to an array of chars - a string ,as said in a previous answer,... or not?

Comment: @user2191288 it is a pointer specifically to an array of *eleven* chars. this is important when doing typed pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @EL10 Yes. I can expand on it there (or here in this answer if you like) to demonstrate how the underlying type makes a significant difference with pointer arithmetic, but so long as you understand that `char *p;` and `char (*p)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];` describe very different things, thats all that really matters.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I understood it, thanks.  In the EXCERSICE FAQs it says that (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1] is equal to  dict0[][MAX_WORD_LEN+1], when I saw that i tought that the array had already memory allocated, It confused me. but with your explanation made it clear.   One more thing, what is "underlying type " ?

Comment: @EL11 it is used in describing the type a pointer is bound to. Example, `char *p;`, the underlying type is `char`. For `char (*p)[N];` the underlying type is `char[N]`. I hope that makes it a bit clearer. It is important, especially when doing pointer arithmetic because the size of the underlying type determines the number of bytes a pointer is actually adjusted when adding/subtracting scalers.